# IBM Connections 4.5 SPI

Tags: ibm-connections

I tried to implement the post event handler using IBM Connections SPI and deployed into IBM Connections using the below link.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Lotus+Connections+3+documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Deploying_an_event_handler_lc3&content=pdcontent

However, I am getting below error in the trace logs.

```
[5/30/14 16:35:32:462 IST] 00000014 EventConfigPa 3 com.ibm.lconn.events.internal.config.EventConfigParser bindVariables: postHandlers.postHandler[@name][6] has value MyHandler null
[5/30/14 16:35:32:474 IST] 00000014 EventConfigPa 3 com.ibm.lconn.events.internal.config.EventConfigParser getPostEventHandlers Handler name: MyHandler, class: com.tcs.Events
[5/30/14 16:35:32:474 IST] 00000014 EventConfigPa 3 com.ibm.lconn.events.internal.config.EventConfigParser getPostEventHandlers Handler name: MyHandler loaded from configuration
[5/30/14 16:35:34:305 IST] 00000030 EventConfigPa 3 com.ibm.lconn.events.internal.config.EventConfigParser bindVariables: postHandlers.postHandler[@name][6] has value MyHandler null
```

Could you please help me in the resolving this issue and also please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: what does your configuration file look like? it's probably not configured properly. check to see if you have any null values in your config file

Comment: <postHandler enabled="true" invoke="SYNC" name="MyHandler" class="com.tcs.Events">
                         <subscriptions>
                                    <subscription source="PROFILES"  type="*" eventName="*"/>
                         </subscriptions>
 </postHandler>
We have registered the MyHandler in event-config.xml file using above configuration.

Comment: Is there any addition config file which we need to update inorder to resolve the above issue.

Comment: yes, specifically look at http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.5+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=IBM_Connections_4.5_Audit_and_Compliance_Enablement&content=pdcontent and check how the data store is configured.